# finding shortest way possible in a matrix on google challenge

Tags: python, shortest-path, maze

I have been trying these google challenges and got stuck on this one. I have written some code to solve the problem, It is giving me correct results but there is one hidden test that I am failing and I have been thinking about it and cannot find the answer. I tried to give an integer answer to verify and found out that answer should be 66. but for some reason I am unable to find where I have made a mistake. As a self learing new programmer any help would be appreciated. looking for ideas to make my code more efficient also any ideas on what could be the problem with the hidden test.

Write a function solution(map) that generates the length of the shortest path from the station door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

```
def distanceMap(Map):
    notVisited = {}              
    distances = {}
    for i in range(len(Map)):
        for j in range(len(Map[0])):
            index = str(i)+str(j)
            notVisited[index] = None
            distances[index] = {}
            if i+1 < len(Map):
                distances[index].update({str(i+1)+str(j):1 if Map[i+1][j]  == 0 else 10000})
            if j+1 < len(Map[0]):
                distances[index].update({str(i)+str(j+1): 1 if Map[i][j+1] == 0 else 10000})
            if i-1 >= 0:
                distances[index].update({str(i-1)+str(j): 1 if Map[i-1][j] == 0 else 10000})
            if j-1 >= 0: 
                distances[index].update({str(i)+str(j-1): 1 if Map[i][j-1] == 0 else 10000})
    return(notVisited,distances)

def shortestPath(notVisited,distances,width,height):
    visited = {}
    current = '00'
    distance = 1
    notVisited[current] = distance
    target = False
    while target != True:
        for neighbour, cost in distances[current].items():
            if neighbour in visited: continue
            newDistance = distance + cost
            if notVisited[neighbour] == None or notVisited[neighbour] > newDistance: notVisited[neighbour] = newDistance
        visited[current] = distance
        del notVisited[current]
        candidates = [node for node in notVisited.items() if node[1]]
        current, distance = sorted(candidates, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
        if current == height+width: target = True
    return(notVisited[height+width])

def solution(Map):
    if len(Map[0]) > 20 or len(Map[0]) < 2 or len(Map) > 20 or len(Map) < 2: return 'invalid map'
    width = str(len(Map[0]) - 1)
    height = str(len(Map)-1)
    notVisited,distances = distanceMap(Map)
    shortestDist = []
    shortestDist.append(shortestPath(notVisited,distances,width,height))
    for i in range(len(Map)):
        for j in range(len(Map[0])):
            neighbours = 0
            if Map[i][j] == 1:
                if i+1 < len(Map) and Map[i+1][j] == 0: neighbours += 1
                if j+1 < len(Map[0]) and Map[i][j+1] == 0: neighbours += 1
                if i-1 >= 0 and Map[i-1][j] == 0: neighbours += 1
                if j-1 >= 0 and Map[i][j-1] == 0: neighbours += 1
                if neighbours > 1:
                    Map[i][j] = 0
                    notVisited, distances = distanceMap(Map)
                    shortestDist.append(shortestPath(notVisited,distances,width,height))
                    Map[i][j] = 1
                    shortest = sorted(shortestDist)[0]
                    if shortest == len(Map)+len(Map[0])-1: return(shortest)
    if shortest > 10000: return('not solvable')
    return(shortest)


maze = [
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]



print(solution(maze))
```

I was able to complete the challenge and this is my final submission

```
def createGraph(Map,height,width):
    graph = {}
    walls = []
    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            index = (i, j)
            graph[index] = []
            if Map[i][j] != 1:
                if i+1 < height:
                    if Map[i+1][j] == 0: graph[index].append((i+1, j))
                if i-1 >= 0:
                    if Map[i-1][j] == 0: graph[index].append((i-1, j))        
                if j+1 < width:
                    if Map[i][j+1] == 0: graph[index].append((i, j+1))         
                if j-1 >= 0:
                    if Map[i][j-1] == 0: graph[index].append((i, j-1))
            else: walls.append((i,j))
    return(graph,walls)

def removableWalls(Map,walls,height,width):
    wallsRemovable = []
    for x in range(len(walls)):
        i = walls[x][0]
        j = walls[x][1]
        passableNeighbours = 0
        if i+1 < height:
            if Map[i+1][j] == 0: passableNeighbours += 1
        if i-1 >= 0:
            if Map[i-1][j] == 0: passableNeighbours += 1       
        if j+1 < width:
            if Map[i][j+1] == 0:passableNeighbours += 1         
        if j-1 >= 0:
            if Map[i][j-1] == 0: passableNeighbours += 1
        if passableNeighbours > 1:wallsRemovable.append(walls[x])
    return wallsRemovable


def findPath(graph,start,finish):
    visited = []
    queue = []
    distances = {}
    distances[start] = 1
    queue.append(start)
    visited.append((0, 0))
    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited.append(neighbour)
                queue.append(neighbour)
                distances[neighbour] = distances[node]+1
    if (finish) not in visited:
        return('solution not found')
    return(distances[finish])

def solution(Map):
    if len(Map[0]) > 20 or len(Map[0]) < 2 or len(Map) > 20 or len(Map) < 2: return 'invalid map'
    shortest = []
    width = len(Map[0])
    height = len(Map)
    graph,wallList = createGraph(Map,height,width)
    shortest.append(findPath(graph,(0,0),(height-1,width-1)))
    walls = removableWalls(Map, wallList, height, width)
    for x in range(len(walls)):
        i = walls[x][0]
        j = walls[x][1]
        Map[i][j] = 0
        graph = createGraph(Map, height, width)[0]
        shortest.append(findPath(graph,(0,0),(height-1,width-1)))
        Map[i][j] = 1
        if min(shortest) == height+width-1: return min(shortest)
    return min(shortest)
    


# Map = [[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
# [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# Map = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#         [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

print(solution(Map))
```

However I would like to do one more thing in the code in future.
Calculate the path from start to finish and save distances to all the nodes and then do the same from Finish to start.
Then remove walls that have a path on more than one of its sides add the distances of neighbours:

**new solution to maze = neighour 1 dist from start + neighbour 2 dist from finish + 1 extra step to cross the removed wall**

this will give a same result but program won't have to search the whole path everytime but  just twice in the beginning.

Comment: To find the shortest path, you need to perform what's known as a breadth-first search:  First find all positions that are distance 1 from the start, then find all that are distance 2, etc.  Keep going until you reach the goal, at which point you will be guaranteed to have found the shortest distance.  You can use a queue to do it, or keep a set of all points at the previous distance.

Comment: I have tried to implement dijkstra algorithm with set start and target nodes and it seems to be working for as many test cases (upto 20x20) I have tried so far. however there is me hidden test that I do not know that is failing for some reason. I am unable it deduce what that might be.

Comment: One problem I see is that you're converting `width` and `height` to strings.  That makes no sense.  You can't do arithmetic on strings.  Leave them as integers.  You're also subtracting one from them, leaving them one too small.  So they aren't width and height.  They're width-1 and height-1.  That doesn't make sense either.  Keep it simple.  Use width and height, and don't try to change them.

Comment: Also, once you have width and height, why do you keep using `len(Map)` and `len(Map[0])`?  That completely defeats the purpose of saving the values in `width` and `height`.  But again, the values being saved are the wrong values (they're one too small), and they're strings, which makes them useless.

Comment: The calls to `update` don't make sense.  All you're doing is updating a single dict value, do just use `d[key] = value`.  Instead, you're doing `d.update({key:value})`, i.e. you're needlessly creating a new, temporary dict, calling `update` with it, then discarding it.  None of that is necessary.

Comment: At a glance, I didn't see in your code where you check to see if removing a single wall helps.  That's the key part of this problem.  I may have missed it, but if that's absent, then it won't solve the challenge.

Comment: Keep in mind that dijkstra's algorithm operates on weighted graphs, which is more general (and slower) than what this problem requires.

Comment: @TomKarzes I was checking the walls that have more than one neighbours that are not a wall and removing those walls, rerun the path finding on new maze and then sorting out the smallest length. That is inside the solution function (for loop)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the replies. It helped me understand the problems and I was able to complete the challenge.

Comment: I have added the final code in post and some future modifications I would like to do

Comment: Good, glad you were able to finish it!